# Send variables to Fragment by new(Var v) or setArguments(bundle)?

Tags: android, fragment

The official guide advise developer use setArguments to send variables.But I prefer `Fragment f = new Fragment(int i);` Because I feel it's more nature...It's that OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send data to your fragment during initialization, you should use `setArguments`, because if later system decides to re-create your fragment, it will choose default constructor (without data), so you should go in the following way:

```
public class Test extends Fragment {

    ....
    public static Test newInstance(<args>) {
        Test myFragment = new Test();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //put data to bundle
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }
    ....
}
```

From the docs:

Default constructor `Fragment()`. Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().